# Mbrace.io Azure f# exception when running as a console application

Tags: f#, mbrace

```
   let task = 
        cloud { return "Hello world!" } 
        |> cluster.Run
```

when i try to run the above piece code in a console application targeting an azure cluster, I get the following exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MBrace.Core.dll
Additional information: Blob stream has already been committed once.
```

This works fine when i run this piece of code in the f# interactive from a .fsx file.

I am on VS2015 using MBrace.Azure (1.1.19) and MBrace.Core (1.0.15). You can find the source code at 
https://github.com/vikranthc/MbraceExperiment
Here is the output from the console.

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm. That's very strange - the computation itself you're running doesn't have anything to do with Storage, so it appears to be an underlying issue with the way MBrace uses storage.

Which version of MBrace are you using and is there anything else happening in your console application?

Comment: Could you please create an issue in https://github.com/mbraceproject/MBrace.Azure? We would need to know the version of visual studio you're using as well as the entire code used in your console application. Thanks

Comment: @eirik I am on VS2015 using MBrace.Azure (1.1.19) and MBrace.Core (1.0.15). I am sharing the github link for this project. [https://github.com/vikranthc/MbraceExperiment](https://github.com/vikranthc/MbraceExperiment)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in MBrace.Azure 1.1.20